# Java - Reference Variable

Tags: java

I am having problem. At my main class, I have:

```
int  ints[] = Type.desc(1000);
int  auxi[] = new int [1000];
auxi = ints;

System.out.println("========== Init =========");
// Insertion Sort
Algoritmos.insertionSort(ints);
ints = auxi;
```

The desc method is:

```
public static int[] desc (int n){
    int aux[];
    aux = new int[n];
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--) {
        aux[pos++] = i;
    }

    return aux;
}
```

The the value of ints and auxi are changed.

How can I save the initial value of the vector ints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I save the initial valeu of the vector ints?

Make a copy of the array, like this:

```
int[] copy = new int[orig.length];
System.arraycopy(orig, 0, copy, 0, orig.length);
```

Note that this makes a *shallow* copy of the array. It does not matter for primitives, but for reference types you may need to make more work to make a copy.

Comment: @RenatoShumi Not really, no: you can also use `clone()` and cast to `int[]`, or `Arrays.copyOf()`.

Comment: As long as you use don't more advanced data structures like `ArrayList`... Yes... (other than what EJP mentioned, i.e. looping by yourself or copyOf(), I mean).

Answer (score 2):

```
int  ints[] = Type.desc(1000);
int  auxi[] = new int [1000];
auxi = ints;
```

> How can I save the initial valeu of the vector ints?

Don't assign it to another variable. The initialization in your second line above is pointless, as you then proceed to assign `ints` to `auxi`. This step doesn't copy the array, it just copies the reference. If you want to keep the original array, change the third line to a loop that copies the elements, or use `Arrays.copyOf()` or `System.arraycopy()`.

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing this

```
auxi = ints;
```

use

```
System.arrayCopy()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
int [] original_array_backup = new int [ints.length]
System.arraycopy(ints, 0, original_array_backup, 0)
```

So you could pass original_array_backup into your algorithm without losing the data and order of your ints array.